# NPM Package tries to write on document and fails

Tags: reactjs, meteor, npm, google-calendar-api

The package is [react-google-calendar-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-calendar-api)

I'm trying to follow a simple example to sign in with Google:

```
import React, {ReactNode, SyntheticEvent} from 'react';
import ApiCalendar from 'react-google-calendar-api';

export default class Calendar extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this);
        }


        handleItemClick(event, name) {
            if (name === 'sign-in') {
                ApiCalendar.handleAuthClick();
              } else if (name === 'sign-out') {
                ApiCalendar.handleSignoutClick();
              }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                        <button
                                onClick={(e) => this.handleItemClick(e, 'sign-in').bind(this)}
                        >
                            sign-in
                        </button>
                        <button
                                onClick={(e) => this.handleItemClick(e, 'sign-out').bind(this)}
                        >
                            sign-out
                        </button>
                </div>
                );
        }
}
```

My Meteor app fails to start up 
[image]

I guess it does not make sense trying to access document, or window, from an external library. Probably I'm missing some React/Javascript concept here.

Comment: Try removing the bind from your handlers inside the buttons, so `onClick={(e) => this.handleItemClick(e, 'sign-in').bind(this)}` becomes `onClick={e => this.handleItemClick(e, 'sign-in')}`. Not sure if this fixes your issue, but it's unnecessary since you binded them in your constructor. It's possible that by binding them again, since you're creating a courier function (hope I'm using that term correctly), you're binding them to the onClick function itself instead of the component. But outside of that I don't know what to tell you

Comment: I've already tried that. Same error. But thanks

Comment: It looks like that lib expects to be run in the browser. I don't know Meteor super well, but are you trying to render server-side?

Comment: The component mounted is on client-side. I can run, for example, jQuery inside any component. So, I don't know what's happening....

Comment: Are you sure your code is running in the browser? An error to the console like that came from the server, and Meteor doesn't propagate errors from client to server? What is the path of this file within your project, and where is it included from?